# Why this MySQL Query Successfully Executes?

Tags: mysql, sql, xss

I am playing with Multilldae's XSS exercise and in one of the exercise(OWASP 2013->A3->Reflected->Pen Test Tool Lookup) my crafted input lead to the following query. The where clause is in a very strange form. And tool_id is an int field.

```
SELECT tool_id, tool_name, phase_to_use, tool_type, comment FROM pen_test_tools 
WHERE tool_id = '2\", \"good\":\"haha';
```

Surprising to me, this query successfully executes and returns the correct result. Could you please tell me why? In my view, the where clause is completely nonsense and MySQL should report an error.

Thanks!

Comment: The `where` clause has a column equal to a constant string.  What is strange about that?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The correct where clause should be WHERE tool_id = 2, not WHERE tool_id = CONSTANT_STRING. But the strange thing is that the later also returns the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because `tool_id` is an integer, so the comparison is done numerically.

MySQL will convert a string to a number in a numeric context.  When it does so, it does 
"silent" conversion, so errors are not reported.  It converts a string based on the leading numbers, so this string becomes `2`.  If there are no leading digits (or minus signs or plus signs after leading spaces), then the value is `0`.

Comment: So MySQL will abandon the rest of the string after character 2? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. When I test WHERE tool_id = '2aaaa', it also returns the correct answer. So MySQL indeed drop all characters after 2.

Comment: @ZillGate . . . MySQL will ignore characters after the numbers in a numeric context.